# How to create a instance

Tags: java, swing

I am having two classes, a main class and class which extends JPanel and implements Runnable. I am trying to create two threads for the same instance of the JPanel class in an actionListener, but i just don't know where to create the JPanel1 object...

//Edit: Button1 is the start of the application .After that , button 2 will appear with a quick animation of labels and when clicked it(button2) will start the same animation too. How can i do whenever one of these buttons is clicked to launch the run method ?

```
public void run() {

            if(isTom){

            repaint();
            revalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            panel.removeAll();
            panel.add(tomLabel1);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            panel.add(tomLabel2);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            panel.add(tomLabel3);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
            panel.add(tomLabel4);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            panel.add(tomLabel5);
            repaint();
            revalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }


            panel.removeAll();
            repaint();
            revalidate();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }

            }



public Game(){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Panel1 key = new Panel1();
        key.addKeyListener(key);
        frame.add(key);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Game();

    }

    public class Panel1 extends JPanel implements KeyListener,Runnable{
    JButton button1 = new JButton("BUTTON1");
    JButton button2 = new JButton("BUTTON2");
    add(button1);add(button2);

        Thread t = new Thread(this); // This works, but i need it inside the actionListener.

         button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    System.out.println("button1");
                    Thread x = new Thread(j);//'j' is an JPanel1 object. I need something like this i guess
                    x.setName("Thread x");});

         button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                    System.out.println("button2");
                    Thread y = new Thread(j);
                    y.setName("Thread y");
                                           });

public void run(){
     System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question here is, you should add more info on what you are trying to do, for example, what these threads going to do. It does look like you are probably going off path from what you are trying to do, so providing that info is probably best.

Comment: Creating Threads around a single instance of a Runnable will have the threads execute the runnable simultaneously. If you don't want that, have the panel class create a Runnable and return it via a getter

Comment: And remember, swing is single threaded and not thread safe

Comment: I'm not sure I understand it either, but maybe you want this:   `Thread y = new Thread(this.Panel1);`  This will run your thread in the same instance of your Panel1 class.

Answer (score 1):

First, Swing is NOT thread safe!  This means that you should NEVER create or modify the UI from outside of context of the Event Dispatching Thread!

Second, Swing is a single threaded environment, this means that you should never block or execute long running code from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread, this will cause the UI to freeze until the block is removed.

Your concept is correct, you implementation is wrong, you should use a Swing `Timer` instead.

Instead of removing and adding labels, use a single label and change it's properties (text/icon, what ever)

See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

[image: Splash]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                try {
                    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    frame.add(new TestPane());
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (IOException exp) {
                    exp.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JButton button1;
        private JButton button2;

        private SplashScreen splashScreen;

        public TestPane() throws IOException {
            button1 = new JButton("Button One");
            button2 = new JButton("Button Two");

            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.add(button1);
            buttons.add(button2);

            button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    splashScreen.run();
                }
            });

            button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    splashScreen.run();
                }
            });

            splashScreen = new SplashScreen();

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            add(splashScreen);
            add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }

    }

    public static  class SplashScreen extends JPanel {

        protected static final int IMAGE_COUNT = 4;

        private JLabel label;
        private Timer timer;

        private int delta;
        private int count;
        private Icon[] icons;

        private Dimension preferredSize;

        public SplashScreen() throws IOException {
            String path = "/images/splash";
            String ext = ".png";
            icons = new Icon[IMAGE_COUNT];
            int maxWidth = 0;
            int maxHeight = 0;
            for (int index = 0; index < IMAGE_COUNT; index++) {
                String name = path + (index + 1) + ext;
                System.out.println(name);
                icons[index] = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(name)));
                maxWidth = Math.max(maxWidth, icons[index].getIconWidth());
                maxHeight = Math.max(maxHeight, icons[index].getIconHeight());
            }
            preferredSize = new Dimension(maxWidth, maxHeight);

            timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (count >= IMAGE_COUNT) {
                        count = IMAGE_COUNT - 2;
                        delta = -1;
                    } else if (count < 0) {
                        ((Timer)e.getSource()).stop();
                    } else {
                        label.setIcon(icons[count]);
                        count += delta;
                    }
                }
            });

            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            label = new JLabel();
            add(label);
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return preferredSize;
        }

        public void run() {

            if (!timer.isRunning()) {

                delta = 1;
                count = 0;
                timer.start();

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I can't use a single label. I have 5 images which i want to be shown like this : adds 1st, waits ,adds 2nd,waits,adds 3rd and so on until the last one, but every single image remains displayed while still ading more and then remove all of them and rerun. So it is like a loading screen

Comment: Yes, you can, you place the images into an array and you use `JLabel#setIcon` to change the single icon

Comment: Yes, but using a Timer, i can not get the same effect as using Thread. I mean the Thread.sleep(). I need a delay inside my timer method, not between executions

Comment: Rubbish, a `Timer` sets up a call-back at regular intervals (say 100 milliseconds) from within which you can make decisions about what you want to do and display, it's like a pseudo-loop

Comment: I've added an example, which plays through 4 images and even plays them back, each image is displayed on the screen for 250 milliseconds, as per the requirements of the `Timer`!

Comment: `javax.swing.Timer` is also safe to use with Swing as it executes it's callbacks within the Event Dispatching Thread, make it safe to update the screen.

Comment: So basically, the timer is started with this line ? splashScreen = new SplashScreen(); And what does the run() method is called ?

Comment: Nope, the `Timer` is started by the `SplashScreen#run` method.  It checks to see if the `Timer` is already running or not.  If it's not, it resets the required variables and starts it running...This means you can control it through something like, a button...

Answer (score 0):

Create a new instance of a Thread with your Panel1 class instance:

```
button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("button1");
                Thread x = new Thread(Panel1.this);
                x.start();
                x.setName("Thread x");});
```

Repeat for the other button with a new Thread object:

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("button2");
                Thread y = new Thread(Panel1.this);
                y.start();
                y.setName("Thread y"); });
```

Panel1.this is referring to the instance of the Panel1 class that is currently running, making sure that your Threads are executing run() of that instance.

Comment: And what relationship does these two panels have with the one that is been displayed?

Comment: I've tried that too but it says "Panel1 cannot be resolved or is not a field" .

Comment: @MadProgrammer Two panels ? I am having only 1 panel (class Panel1)

Comment: Sorry, was supposed to be `Panel1.this` instead, edited answer

Comment: So, what does "Panel1.this" mean more specific ? It calls the instance of Panel1 ?

Comment: Yes, added a comment in answer. `Panel1.this` is a way to refer to the instance of outside class from the inner class. You need to do this since you're instantiating your Thread from an anonymous ActionListener

Comment: You do realise that the OP is violating the single thread rules of Swing?  That this would allow them to, technically, produce a race condition as the two threads battle to update the UI as they see fit :P

Comment: Perhaps that is the OP's end goal -- who know? :) I'm just trying to address the problem at hand.

Comment: Actually they do not race. On startup only the first button will show, which on click will start the animation and add the second button. When the second button is clicked, panel is cleared and adds the animation and again + second button again, and so on . So button1 isn't contained anymore.

Comment: One more quick question .. Couldn't i just use instead of "Thread x = new Thread(Panel1.this);" something like JPanel1 p = new JPanel1();Thread x = new Thread(p); ? But i just don't know where to write this .

Comment: What is JPanel1 and what does it do?

Comment: @AXL It is still violating the single thread rules of Swing - Swing could be painting the screen when you try to update it, causing a race condition and producing paint artifacts...

Comment: @AXL You can't use `JPanel1 p = new JPanel1();Thread x = new Thread(p);` as `p` has no relationship to what is displayed on the screen...

Comment: JPanel1 is a class which extends JPanel, doesn't that make it a jpanel ?

Comment: @AXL, as MadProgrammer pointed out, you can't just create another random panel, it needs to be a Runnable class that has your animation code in the run() method.  You could also put all the animation logic into your Panel1 class run() method, which is not doing much currently.